# T4MVC for direct to ActionName in Post area it doesn't work

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, t4mvc

When i use T4MVC for direct to ActionName in Post Area , but it doesn't work when  i see render html code

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action(MVC.Post.Admin.ActionNames.Posts,MVC.Post.Admin.Name, new {area = MVC.Post.Name})"><i class="icon-user-follow"></i>showPost</a>
```

when i see View Page Source in Firefox
i see this code

```html
 <a href="/?area=Post">showPost</a>
```

Please let me know what I am doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use `MVC.AreaName.SomeController.SomeAction()`

```
href="@Url.Action(result: MVC.Post.Admin.Posts())"
```